# Closed as dupe. Can't see duplicate link

Tags: bug

I know the stack crew is messing with the close experience but I haven't heard anything about closing as dupe no longer offering a link to the dupe. Please let me know what's going on when I see [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/408229/where-to-validate-mandatory-parameters-in-the-function-body-or-already-with-a-c):

[image]

Comment: The [question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345289/closed-as-a-duplicate-but-the-duplicate-list-is-empty) says that this problem has been fixed. Details are in the accepted answer there.

Answer (score 3):

[Closed as a duplicate, but the duplicate list is empty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345289/closed-as-a-duplicate-but-the-duplicate-list-is-empty?noredirect=1&lq=1)

> Yes: this is definitely an issue, and No: it does not seem to be
>   related to the duplicate questions not having any answers (an issue
>   that was resolved months ago).
>
> It is a new issue having to do with a specific scenario where the post
>   owner accepts duplicate suggestions and self-closes as duplicate.
>   While it is definitely occurring, I cannot repro locally.
>
> I am adding some fixes to related issues here that may end up taking
>   care of it, a fix for the "duplicate comments" not being deleted, and
>   additional logging to aid in further debugging should the issue
>   continue. (Changes have not yet been merged, I will update when that
>   has happened, but I wanted to update here that this is being looked
>   at).

-- [Yaakov Ellis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/51/yaakov-ellis)